# Where's error in implementation of minimax algorithm?

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe, minimax

There is one little problem with it's implementation for a Tic-Tac-Toe game. For the following combination:

```
['x', 'o', 'e',  
 'o', ' e', 'e',  
 'e', ' e', 'e']
```

the best choice would be

```
['x', 'o', 'e',  
 'o', ' x', 'e',  
 'e', ' e', 'e']
```

but it returns as I suppose the nearest suitable one:

```
['x', 'o', 'x',  
 'o', ' e', 'e',  
 'e', ' e', 'e']
```

And in this case AI loses.
Here is the code:

```
var board = ['x', 'o', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e'];
var signPlayer = 'o';
var signAI = (signPlayer === 'x') ? 'o' : 'x';

game = {
    over: function(board) {
        for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i += 3) {
            if (board[i] === board[i + 1] && board[i + 1] === board[i + 2]) {
                return board[i] !== 'e' ? board[i] : false;
            }
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (board[j] === board[j + 3] && board[j + 3] === board[j + 6]) {
                return board[j] !== 'e' ? board[j] : false;
            }
        }
        if ((board[4] === board[0] && board[4] === board[8]) || 
        (board[4] === board[2] && board[4] === board[6])) {
            return board[4] !== 'e' ? board[4] : false;
        }
        return ( board.every(function(element) {
            return element !== 'e';
        })) 
    },
    winner: function(board) {
        return game.over(board);
    },
    possible_moves: function(board, sign) {
        var testBoard = [], 
        nextBoard;
        for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            nextBoard = board.slice();
            if (nextBoard[i] === 'e') {
                nextBoard[i] = sign;
                testBoard.push(nextBoard);
            }
        }
        return testBoard;
    }
}

function moveScore(board) {
    var result = game.winner(board);

    if (result === signPlayer) {
        return -100;
    }
    if (result === signAI) {
        return +100;
    }
    return 0;
    //Game is a draw
}

function max(board) {

    if (game.over(board)) {
        return board;
    }
    var newGame = [];
    var bestMove = [];
    var score;
    var best_score = -Infinity;
    var movesArray = game.possible_moves(board, signAI);

    for (var i = 0; i < movesArray.length; i++) {
        newGame = movesArray[i].slice();
        score = moveScore(min(newGame));
        if (score > best_score) {
            best_score = score;
            bestMove = newGame;
        }
    }
    return bestMove;
}

function min(board) {

    if (game.over(board)) {
        return board;
    }
    var newGame = [];
    var worstMove = [];
    var score;
    var worst_score = +Infinity;
    var movesArray = game.possible_moves(board, signPlayer);

    for (var i = 0; i < movesArray.length; i++) {
        newGame = movesArray[i].slice();
        score = moveScore(max(newGame));
        if (score < worst_score) {
            worst_score = score;
            worstMove = newGame;
        }
    }
    return worstMove;
}

max(board);
```

Comment: Your title is implying that there is a bug in JavaScript. Instead it's much more likely your implementation of the algorithm is flawed. You should try debugging it first though.

Comment: I haven't found an error still(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the following issues:

- The `over` method gives wrong output for some boards, like for instance for this board:

  ```
  ['e', 'e', 'e', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'x', 'x', 'e']
  ```

  It will actually stop looking after it finds the three `e` values in the first three elements and return `false`, i.e. it does not see the win on the second row for `o`. To fix, change this line:

  ```
  return board[i] !== 'e' ? board[i] : false;
  ```

  to:

  ```
  if (board[i] !== 'e') return board[i];
  ```

  This will make the function continue with the other checks if it finds three `e` in a row. Similar fixes are necessary in the other loops (except the very last one).
- Although the minimax algorithm visits the nodes in the search tree succesfully, it does not carry the found leaf-score (0, -100 or 100) back up in the search tree. Instead you recalculate each position's score by just looking at a static board configuration, ignoring the best/worst score you could get from the recursive call. To fix this, let the *min* and *max* function not only return the best move, but also the score associated with it. So replace this:

  ```
  return bestMove;
  ```

  with:

  ```
  return [best_score, bestMove];
  ```

  And then you pick up the score from the recursive call, if you replace this:

  ```
  score = moveScore(min(newGame));
  ```

  with:

  ```
  score = min(newGame)[0];
  ```

  You need to do a similar change for the case where the game is over. Replace this:

  ```
  if (game.over(board)) {
      return board;
  }
  ```

  with:

  ```
  if (game.over(board)) {
      return [moveScore(board), []];
  }
  ```

  Note that this *is* the only right moment to call *moveScore*. The second element of the array should be the best move, but as there is no move, it is better to just use an empty array for that.
- This is a minor issue: you don't actually use the best move you get from the main call to *max*. With the above change, you could get both the best move *and* its score in the main call:

  ```
  [score, nextBoard] = max(board);
  ```

Here is your corrected code, with some additional code at the end to allow a game to be played by clicking on a 3x3 grid. For that purpose I have changed the code `e` to a space, as it looks better on a printed board:

```js
var board = ['x', 'o', ' ', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '];
var signPlayer = 'o';
var signAI = (signPlayer === 'x') ? 'o' : 'x';

var game = {
    over: function(board) {
        for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i += 3) {
            if (board[i] === board[i + 1] && board[i + 1] === board[i + 2]) {
                //return board[i] !== ' ' ? board[i] : false;
                if (board[i] !== ' ') return board[i];
            }
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (board[j] === board[j + 3] && board[j + 3] === board[j + 6]) {
                //return board[j] !== ' ' ? board[j] : false;
                if (board[j] !== ' ') return board[j];
            }
        }
        if ((board[4] === board[0] && board[4] === board[8]) || 
                (board[4] === board[2] && board[4] === board[6])) {
            //return board[4] !== ' ' ? board[4] : false;
            if (board[4] !== ' ') return board[4];
        }
        return ( board.every(function(element) {
            return element !== ' ';
        })) 
    },
    winner: function(board) {
        return game.over(board);
    },
    possible_moves: function(board, sign) {
        var testBoard = [], 
        nextBoard;
        for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            nextBoard = board.slice();
            if (nextBoard[i] === ' ') {
                nextBoard[i] = sign;
                testBoard.push(nextBoard);
            }
        }
        return testBoard;
    }
}

function moveScore(board) {
    var result = game.winner(board);

    if (result === signPlayer) {
        return -100;
    }
    if (result === signAI) {
        return +100;
    }
    return 0;
    //Game is a draw
}

function max(board) {
    //if (game.over(board)) {
    //    return board;
    //}
    if (game.over(board)) {
        return [moveScore(board), []];
    }
    var newGame = [];
    var bestMove = [];
    var score;
    var best_score = -Infinity;
    var movesArray = game.possible_moves(board, signAI);
    for (var i = 0; i < movesArray.length; i++) {
        newGame = movesArray[i].slice();
        //score = moveScore(min(newGame));
        score = min(newGame)[0];
        if (score > best_score) {
            best_score = score;
            bestMove = newGame;
        }
    }
    //return bestMove;
    return [best_score, bestMove];
}

function min(board) {
    //if (game.over(board)) {
    //    return board;
    //}
    if (game.over(board)) {
        return [moveScore(board), []];
    }
    var newGame = [];
    var worstMove = [];
    var score;
    var worst_score = +Infinity;
    var movesArray = game.possible_moves(board, signPlayer);

    for (var i = 0; i < movesArray.length; i++) {
        newGame = movesArray[i].slice();
        //score = moveScore(max(newGame));
        score = max(newGame)[0];
        if (score < worst_score) {
            worst_score = score;
            worstMove = newGame;
        }
    }
    //return worstMove;
    return [worst_score, worstMove];
}

// Extra code for adding a simple GUI

var board = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '];
var score = null;

var tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td'));
var table = document.querySelector('table');
var span = document.querySelector('span');

function display(board, score) {
    board.forEach( (v, i) => tds[i].textContent = v );
    span.textContent = score;
}
display(board);

table.onclick = function (e) {
    var i = tds.indexOf(e.target);
    if (i == -1 || board[i] !== ' ' || game.over(board)) return;
    board[i] = signPlayer;
    display(board);
    [score, board] = max(board, 1);
    display(board, score);
}
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid; width: 20px; text-align: center; cursor: hand }
tr { height: 25px; v-align: middle }
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<div>
Score: <span></span>
</div>
```

#### Final note

I have just made the corrections to make it work, but note there are several ways to improve the efficiency. This you can do by using an alpha-beta search, tracking scores for already evaluated boards, while mapping similar boards by translations (turning, mirroring), and mutating boards instead of creating a new board each time you play a move.

Comment: I'm sincerely impressed by the amount of work, you've done with my code, but(:
[ x ] [   ] [ x ]

Comment: [ x ] [ ] [ x ]

Comment: [ x ] [ ] [ x ]
[    ] [ ] [    ]

Comment: the thing is it not working properly still, I 've found situation when user can win

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126369/discussion-between-taras-yaremkiv-and-trincot).

Comment: I corrected the code. I had accidentally put my corrections in comments, and left yours in place (in the `winner` function). So now it is the other way around and seems to work OK. Can you check?